# Android Fragment Shared Element transition without fragmentTransaction.replace()

Tags: android, fragment-transitions

I can not do exactly what I want with the transitions to the initialization of my fragments:

```
 val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val fragments = fragmentManager.fragments
    if (fragments.isNotEmpty())
        for (oldFragment in fragments)
            if (oldFragment.isAdded && (!second || oldFragment.tag?.substring(0, userId.length)!!.contains(fragmentTag)))
                fragmentTransaction.hide(oldFragment)

    //create or show
    var fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag + userId) as? F_Base

    if (fragment == null || mKillFrags.contains(fragmentTag) || killFragment) {
        if (fragment != null)
            fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment)

        fragment = createFragmentByTag(fragmentTag, bundle)

        if (fragment == null) {
            UIUtils.broadcastMessage(R.string.error)

            return false
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            fragment.sharedElementEnterTransition = DetailsTransition()
            fragment.sharedElementReturnTransition = null
            fragment.enterTransition = Fade()
            fragment.exitTransition = null
        }

        //todo test animation
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && sharedView.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (view in sharedView)
                fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(view, view.transitionName.substring(0, view.transitionName.lastIndexOf("_")))
            fragmentTransaction.replace(content.id, fragment, fragmentTag)
        } else
        fragmentTransaction.add(content.id, fragment, fragmentTag + userId)
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment)
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

In this case the transitions work because the initialization of the fragments pass by `fragmentTransaction.replace()` but I do not want to destroy my current fragment, except that if I leave `fragmentTransaction.add()` my transition is not taken.

Do you have a solution ?